# The return type 'User?' isn't a 'User', as required by the closure's context. Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to wrap my head around implementing FireBase auth while following some tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Sa60ZxFgSI&t=319s like this one), but recent Dart null-safety migration has been painful for me.

Currently stuck at writing User stream for tracking user auth state changes

User class:

```
class User {

  final String uid;
  
  User({ this.uid });

}
```

Auth Service:

```
import 'package:finances/models/user.dart' as u;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthenticationService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

// create user obj based on firebase user
  u.User? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? u.User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().
      map((User firebaseUser) => (firebaseUser != null) ? u.User(uid: firebaseUser.uid) : null


    );
  }
  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The samples are pretty basic.

Errors:

```
The argument type 'User Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'. (Documentation)
The return type 'User?' isn't a 'User', as required by the closure's context.
```

and some more errors in terminal:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64...
lib/services/auth_service.dart:15:57: Error: A value of type 'User/*1*/?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'User/*2*/'.
 - 'User/*1*/' is from 'package:finances/models/user.dart' ('lib/models/user.dart').
 - 'User/*2*/' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('/D:/flutterSDK/flutter_windows_2.8.1-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-3.3.8/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
      map((User firebaseUser) => (firebaseUser != null) ? u.User(uid: firebaseUser.uid) : null
                                                        ^
lib/services/auth_service.dart:15:11: Error: The argument type 'User Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)' because 'User?' is nullable and 'User' isn't.
 - 'User' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('/D:/flutterSDK/flutter_windows_2.8.1-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-3.3.8/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
      map((User firebaseUser) => (firebaseUser != null) ? u.User(uid: firebaseUser.uid) : null
```

Can someone give me a clue or hint on how to solve this issue? Same library naming after they deprecated FirebaseUser doesn't help as well.

Comment: Your `Stream<User> get user {` claims to return a `Stream<User>`, but then in is implementation you return `null`. So it should be ` Stream<User?>`.

Answer (score 2):

In this code, your function takes a not nullable user as arg (but you are still checking whether it is null in the code of that function so it doesn't make sense to make it not nullable).

```
u.User? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user)
  return user != null ? u.User(uid: user.uid) : null;
}
```

It should be this:

```
u.User? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user)
```

It is probably throwing an error because you are getting a nullable user from the `result.user` and then you are casting it as not nullable with the `!` in the line underneath.

```
User? user = result.user;
return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
```